# List rows order by oldest time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am a bit new in sql and I have this problem to get an specific information from three tables. I have those three tables.

employee table

[image]

company table

[image]

employment table

[image]

EmployeeID in Employment is FK
CompanyID in Company is FK
EmploymentID in Emplyment is PK
NULL in EmploymentEndDate in Employment means that worker is currently working there.

I have been trying this but is not working

```
select Company.CompanyName as CompanyName , CONCAT( Employee.FirstName, ' ' ,Employee.LastName) as EmployeeName , Employment.EmploymentStartDate from Employment LEFT JOIN Employee on Employee.EmployeeID = Employment.EmployeeID 
LEFT JOIN Company on Company.CompanyID = Employment.CompanyID 
where Employment.EmploymentEndDate is null 
and EXISTS(SELECT Employment.CompanyID, MAX(DATEDIFF( DAY,Employment.EmploymentStartDate ,GETDATE())) as MaxDate FROM  Employment where  Employment.EmploymentEndDate is null group by CompanyID)
```

and is giving me this result:

[image]

which is wrong because from company "Steve's Widgets Inc" I expect only John Doe which is the most old worker.

This is exactly what I want, List all Companies and gives the name and start date of the Employee that has been working in the Company the longest out of all Employees that are currently working there.
(Expected Columns: CompanyName, EmployeeName, EmploymentStartDate)

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is a little unclear. Please edit to make the question more direct.
Also, please format the SQL code to make it more readable.

Comment: @EricWu this is what I want, List all Companies and gives the name and start date of the Employee that has been working in the Company the longest out of all Employees that are currently working there.
(Expected Columns: CompanyName, EmployeeName, EmploymentStartDate)

Comment: There is a conflict between "most old" and "working in the Company the longest". Are you interested in maximum age or minimum hire date? It's also helpful to provide DDL and sample data in consumable form rather than just pictures of data. Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 0):

```
with oldest (companyId, empStart) as 
(
select companyId, min(EmploymentStartDate) 
from Employment
where EmploymentEndDate is null
group by companyId
)
select c.CompanyName, e.Firstname + ' ' + e.LastName as employeeName, em.employmentStartDate
from Employment em
inner join oldest o on em.CompanyId = o.CompanyID and em.employmentStartDate = o.empStart
inner join employee e on em.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
inner join company c on em.CompanyId = c.CompanyId;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use first value it would look something like this, note I have not used first value on sql server (only on db2) and I did not test this since I don't have an sql server on hand.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Company.CompanyName, 
  CONCAT(Employee.FirstName, ' ', Employee.LastName) AS EmployeeName,
  FIRST_VALUE(Employment.EmploymentStartDate) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY Company.CompanyName, CONCAT(Employee.FirstName, ' ', Employee.LastName) 
      ORDER BY Employment.EmploymentStartDate ASC 
      RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) AS StartDate
FROM Employment 
JOIN Company ON Employment.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
JOIN Employee ON Employment.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID
WHERE Employment.EmploymentEndDate IS NULL
```